# Set value of a variable from a function

Tags: javascript, html

Here I want to set id in function 3. If I call function 2 it should set id = 2 in function 3. Or if I call function 1 it should set id = 1 in function 3.

```
var id;
```

**function - 1**

```
function load() {
id = 1;
}
```

**function - 2**

```
function load1() {
id = 2;
}
```

**function - 3**

```
function getid() {
qid = id
}
```

Is there any way it is possible.

Comment: where you're facing problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call function 3 in function 1 and 2

```
var id;
//function - 1

function load() {
    getid(1);
    //id = 1;
}
//function - 2

function load1() {
    getid(2);
    //id = 2;
}
//function - 3

function getid(param) {
    id = param;
}
```

Comment: cannot call that function inside each function as there are more events. Is there any way I can globally set that variable from function ?

Comment: Your current code already sets that variable in a global manner. Also please elaborate by what you mean regarding more events.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to pass a variable to `getid` and use it as is, you would place the function call for `getid` inside `load` and `load1`.

```
var id;
function load() {
    id = 1;
    getid();
}
function load1() {
    id = 2;
    getid();
}
function getid() {
    qid = id;
}
```